# Let $V$ be the set of all solutions of homogeneous linear differential equation $y''-3y'+2y=0$. Then is $V$ a vector space or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

On solving this differential equation we get $y=e^x$ and $y=e^{2x}$ as solutions, but the sum of these solutions does not belong to $V$.

So how is this a vector space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions of $y''-3y'+2y=0$ then also $ay_1+by_2$ is a solution for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. In fact,
$$(ay_1+by_2)''-3(ay_1+by_2)'+2(ay_1+by_2)\\=(ay_1''+by_2'')-3(ay_1'+by_2')+2(ay_1+by_2)\\
=(ay_1''-3ay_1'+2ay_1)+(by_2''-3by_2'+2by_2)\\=
a(y_1''-3y_1'+2y_1)+b(y_2''-3y_2'+2y_2)=a\cdot 0+b\cdot0=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

> but addition of this solution do not belongs to V.

Really?

Set $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=e^{2x}$.

Then,

$$(f+g)'' - 3(f+g)' + 2(f+g)=\\
=(e^x + e^{2x})'' - 3(e^x + e^{2x})'+2(e^x + e^{2x})=\\
=e^x + 4e^{2x} - 3e^x - 6e^{2x} + 2e^x + 2e^{2x}$$

Are you sure the result is not $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the set of solutions $y$ of the differential equation $y'' - 3y' +2y = 0$ forms the kernel of the linear differential operator $D^2 - 3D + 2I$, where $Dy = y'$ and $Iy = y$. Since the kernel of a linear transformation is always a subspace of the domain vector space, the set of solutions $y$ forms a vector space.